# How to setup “application/ld+json” Schema.org meta data in ASP.NET 3.5 dynamically using C#

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0, asp.net-3.5, json-ld

How can I dynamically create "application/ld+json" SEO Schema.org meta data in ASP.NET 3.5 using C#?

Is there any tool available for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by appending schema content to a stringbuilder and append to head

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("<script type=\"application/ld+json\">");
sb.AppendFormat("{{");
sb.AppendFormat("\"@context\"" + ":" + "\"http://schema.org\"");
sb.AppendFormat(",");
sb.AppendFormat("\"@type\"" + ":" + "\"Article\"");
sb.AppendFormat(",");  
sb.AppendFormat("\"headline\"" + ":" + "\"" + "Test article" + "\"");
 sb.AppendFormat("}}");
 sb.AppendFormat("</script>");                        
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
```

Comment: This may work but not  a very handy way of doing the same :)